# Nginx suddendly responds with Error 404 on all my sites-enabled - localhost

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I don't know what went wrong, but suddendly my nginx localhost server is giving me Error 404 on all my localhost sites.

By running `nginx -t` I get this

```
nginx -t
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2017/02/07 22:53:36 [warn] 9580#0: the "user" directive makes sense only  if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2017/02/07 22:53:36 [warn] 9580#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/02/07 22:53:36 [warn] 9580#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2017/02/07 22:53:36 [emerg] 9580#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13:  Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

And every time I try to access any of my `sites-enabled` websites it throws `Error 404`

I've install and uninstalled `php5-fpm` even `php` itself.

Still nothing

Any ideas?

PS = I'm on Linux mint Rafael (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: First, you need to read the error messages.

Comment: What has changed recently? I looks like a permissions problem. What happened when you restarted Nginx? Server restarts aren't usually necessary but sometimes can be an interesting diagnostic tool.

Comment: It just says 'Restarting Nginx [OK]' not a problem as it seems

Comment: I've added a website into sites-enabled, but it wasn't giving me any trouble, I already deleted the symlink, but the problem presists :/

Comment: The weird thing, is that the 'Welcome to NGINX' start page works

Comment: I wanted to know if restarting Nginx fixes the problem. Roll back your changes to the Nginx configuration and symlinks (etc), test what works and what doesn't, until you reach a stable state. Then reapply your changes until you work out what the problem is. Build your Nginx new site config up slowly.

Comment: Also php5-fpm won't start :/, Okay I'll try that way, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your command with all the privilages.

```
sudo nginx -t
```

it will work. I had the same problem.